# Why am I getting a "You've reached your question limit. [...] you might need a break" message, when my questions have been well-received?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I went to ask a new question on the main EE site, but SE gave me the standard warning, "You have reached your question limit. It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!" that it gives before a question ban.

It says that my recent questions were poorly received, but from what I can see they weren't. My most recent question currently has 3 upvotes and a few well received answers, and my question before that has an upvote and was quite useful.

Why am I at a question limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you got points you to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543) that explains how this block works, and why it exists. You can also read more about it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited):

> ***This block is only temporary, but much longer blocks exist in the system.*** We're trying to slow you down and provide you with more guidance now, in hopes that you avoid a much longer period where the system won't accept questions from your account. Please take some time to revisit and improve your previous questions wherever possible.

As the message noted, it is taking into account the last 4 questions you asked, which, [as Voltage Spike noted](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9651/71136), takes into account a deleted and downvoted question you asked back in January.

There is no way to manually lift this temporary block, but the upside is that it is only gonna last a single day — like noted in the quote above, the point is not to prevent you from asking question altogether, but instead to have you take a break between asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it looks like a bug. I'm wondering if it's adding up score since the 4th question on the newest list was deleted but had a very bad score which would have set you below zero (which might be their metric but I'm not sure). To find out, try posting a question now since I upvoted two of your other questions.

If that doesn't work, you might have to wait until a CM looks at it.

Comment: Nope, still got the issue. How strange